# C# WPF Controls in WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, wrappanel

[image]Hey guys,
I'm trying to add some controls via code, but I have one little problem.
I have checkboxes inside WrapPanel. Checkboxes are transformed to be 1.5x bigger. When I changing size of window, they're colliding with each other.
Without transforming everything is normal. How to fix it?

```
        List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> CheckboxList = new List<CheckBox>();

        public List<string> Users = new List<string> { "First Student", "Very First Student", "Second Student", "Student Student" };

        for (int i = 0; i < Users.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckboxList.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox());
            heckboxList[i].RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1.5,1.5);

            CheckboxList[i].Content = Users[i];
            CheckboxList[i].Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
            Panel.Children.Add(CheckboxList[i]);             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you create the wrap panel?

Comment: WrapPanel is created by Xaml:  <WrapPanel x:Name="Panel" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,85,0"/> inside grid

Comment: You are setting to 0 the left and right  margin, set it to 10 instead. Margin="10,10,85,0"/

Comment: You meant (10,0,95,0)? Both options didn't helped though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RenderTransform` property is used to get/set transform that affects only the control's appearance and does not affect its layout logic. What you want though is to transform your controls both logically and visually, and to achieve that you should use `LayoutTransform` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be very pretty, but you could apply the RenderTransform to the panel itself, the children are transformed as well.

The reason why it is not pretty is that the panel gets resized, so you'll have to apply a new size based on the transformation values.

A code snippet like this could be used:

```
double xScale = 1.5;
double yScale = 1.5;

Panel.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(xScale, yScale);
Panel.Width = Panel.Width / xScale;
Panel.Height = Panel.Height / yScale;

List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> CheckboxList = new List<CheckBox>();

List<string> users = new List<string> { "First Student", "Very First Student", "Second Student", "Student Student" };

foreach (string user in users)
{
    CheckBox newItem = new CheckBox();
    newItem.Content = user;
    Panel.Children.Add(newItem);
}
```